# How to fix Javascript, I can't click the img to toggle sub-menu after adding JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on a feature that allows a sub-menu to open when clicking on a profile image. The desired behavior is that when I click the profile image, the sub-menu should open and the `open-menu` class should be added to it. Additionally, when I click outside the sub-menu box, the sub-menu should close, removing the `open-menu` class.

I have already implemented the code for this functionality, but I'm facing an issue where the profile image is not clickable initially. The sub-menu opens and closes perfectly after the first click outside the box, but I can't seem to click the profile image itself to trigger the sub-menu.

I've done what I can, I might need help, Thanks in advance!

```js
let subMenu = document.getElementById("subMenu");

function toggleMenu(open) {
  if (open) {
    subMenu.classList.add("open-menu");
  } else {
    subMenu.classList.remove("open-menu");
  }
}

function isClickedInsideSubMenu(clickedElement) {
  return subMenu.contains(clickedElement);
}

function handleProfileClick() {
  if (subMenu.classList.contains("open-menu")) {
    // Submenu is already open, so we close it
    toggleMenu(false);
  } else {
    // Submenu is not open, so we open it
    toggleMenu(true);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  const clickedElement = event.target;
  const isInsideSubMenu = isClickedInsideSubMenu(clickedElement);

  if (!isInsideSubMenu && subMenu.classList.contains("open-menu")) {
    toggleMenu(false);
  }
});
```

```css
/* popup profile submenu */

.sub-menu-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: var(--tran-02);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub-menu-wrap.open-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 320px;
}

.sub-menu {
  background-color: var(--bg-1);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: var(--std-radius);
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
}

.user-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.user-box {
  background-color: var(--bg-1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
}

.user-info p1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-1);
  margin: 0;
}

.user-info p2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--text-1);
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.user-info img {
  width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.sub-menu hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--color_Light3);
  margin: 10px 0 10px;
}

.sub-menu-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-1);
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sub-menu-link p {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.see-profile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-1);
  padding: 10px;
}

.see-profile p {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-menu-link i {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--color_Light1);
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sub-menu-link span {
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.sub-menu-link:hover,
.see-profile:hover,
.user-info:hover {
  background-color: var(--color_White);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 4px 6px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px -1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider"></div>
<img src="../img/profile.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" onclick="handleProfileClick()" />

<div class="sub-menu-wrap" id="subMenu">
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <div class="user-box">
      <div class="user-info">
        <img src="../img/profile.jpg" alt="Sub Profile Picture" />
        <div class="h3-wrapper">
          <p1 class="user">Arian Checa</p1>
          <p2 class="position">administrator</p2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <a href="#" class="see-profile">
        <p>See Profile</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
      <i class='bx bx-cog'></i>
      <p>Settings</p>
      <span>></span>
    </a>
    <a href="../auth/logout.php" class="sub-menu-link" id="logout-link">
      <i class='bx bx-log-out'></i>
      <p>Logout</p>
      <span>></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the photo of the sub-menu box
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KEng.png)

Comment: I added the wrong question it should be "How to fix Javascript, I can't click the img to toggle sub-menu after adding JS"

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem?

Comment: Hi sir Nico, this is a JS problem, I can't edit the question

Comment: You can _edit_ your question, and fix the title ...

Comment: okay will do, just a minute

Comment: We're missing a bunch of CSS it seems. Lots of `var(..)` calls that aren't defined in the code you've provided.

Comment: "*The sub-menu opens and closes perfectly after the first click outside the box,*" - outside which box? Where is it (visually, on screen), because clicking anywhere on the demo doesn't seem to open/do anything here (or on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9wsv3mt7/)? Are you certain you've recreated your problem?

Comment: the sub-menu has a box similar to facebook's profile dropdown menu (my sub-menu), what I'm trying to acomplish is that when I click outside the sub-menu box, it should close the sub-menu box

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is why it's failing the fist time but you always pass false to the toggle menu function. I would rewrite that like this

```
function toggleMenu() {
  subMenu.classList.toggle("open-menu");
}
```

Also this method too:

```
 function isClickedInsideSubMenu(clickedElement) {
   return subMenu === clickedElement ||    subMenu.contains(clickedElement);
}
```

entire code would be:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let subMenu = document.getElementById("subMenu");

    function toggleMenu() {
      subMenu.classList.toggle("open-menu");
    }

     function isClickedInsideSubMenu(clickedElement) {
       return subMenu === clickedElement || subMenu.contains(clickedElement);
    }

    function handleProfileClick() {
      toggleMenu(); // Simply toggle the menu without passing any parameter
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      const clickedElement = event.target;
      const isInsideSubMenu = isClickedInsideSubMenu(clickedElement);

      if (!isInsideSubMenu && subMenu.classList.contains("open-menu")) {
        toggleMenu(); // Close the menu when clicked outside if it's already open
      }
    });
});
```